# Postgres 9.6 - Unique constraint on array of JSONB key for "contains" operator

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

We have a Postgres (9.6) table `my_table` with a row `email_address jsonb[] NOT NULL`:

```
DROP TABLE my_table;
CREATE TABLE my_table (email_address jsonb NOT NULL);
```

We want to store an array of email addresses as JSONB (for the sake of this example, I'll only keep the `address` key):

```
INSERT INTO my_table (email_address)
VALUES (ARRAY[ $${"address": "A"}$$::jsonb,
               $${"address": "B"}$$::jsonb,
               $${"address": "C"}$$::jsonb ]);

INSERT INTO my_table (email_address)
VALUES (ARRAY[ $${"address": "D"}$$::jsonb ]);
```

We want to make sure that each of the element we add to the array have a unique set of `address`.

```
-- ["A", "B"] <@ ["A", "B", "C"], SHOULD FAIL
INSERT INTO my_table (email_address)
VALUES (ARRAY[ $${"address": "A"}$$::jsonb, $${"address": "B"}$$::jsonb ]

-- ["A", "D"] IS UNIQUE SET, SHOULD SUCCEED
INSERT INTO my_table (email_address)
VALUES (ARRAY[ $${"address": "A"}$$::jsonb, $${"address": "D"}$$::jsonb ];
```

We were thinking about a exclusion constraint using a function maybe? We are currently trying to "map" the `jsonb[]` into a `text[]` (`[{address: "A"}, {address: "B"}]` into `["A", "B"]`) to perform a simple `@>` operation but we struggle to obtain any convincing result.

Our question is: Is such a constraint possible (if yes any help on the code would be greatly appreciated), and if not what would be the best way to implement such a system without having to create another table?

Comment: why are you storing these in json, and not just an array of text, `text[]`. Or even better as a [custom e-mail type.](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/165923/2639)

Comment: We have some complementary information to store with this email address as a Boolean field "preferred" and other data that I didn't included in this example to keep it simple.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgres 9.6 - Create unique index for json array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43220068/postgres-9-6-create-unique-index-for-json-array)

Comment: This is almost exactly the same question as the earlier. It won't work, neither with an exclusion constraint. `@>` is not [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) so it's inherently wrong for exclusion anyway. The only one which could work is the `&&` for arrays, but that's not supported by GiST at the moment.

Comment: It's not really the same, one is to index each individual element of an array, which is not the question here. Also I don't want to deal with commutativity, I really want to use `@>` only.

Comment: Should this fail or succeed? `['A', 'B'] <@ ['A']`

Comment: If `['A']` is present in my DB and I attempt to insert `['A', 'B']`, it should successfully insert `['A', 'B']`. I only care about `@>`